# Mass date update using eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How to perform a bulk-update of multiple `Comment` records' publish dates with **+1 week** period? The illustration of the desired result:

```php
$interval = CarbonInterval::week(); // 1 week interval, that needs to fit into below query
Comment::where('id', '>', 10)->update('publish_date', ...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DB::raw()` to execute arbitrary code in your database - just keep in mind that it might not be portable to other DB engines.

The following should do the trick in **MySQL** and other engines that support **DATE_ADD** function:

```php
Comment::where('id', '>', 10)->update(['publish_date' => DB::raw('DATE_ADD("publish_date", INTERVAL 1 WEEK)')]);
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but isn't there a way to do this by using eloquent natively?

Comment: Not if you want to update multiple rows with a single query. There is the increment method in the builder, but it works by adding an integer to given column which won't work for columns that contain a datetime value

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs you can do this:

`` App\Models\Comment::where('id', '>', 10)->update([
    'publish_date' => Carbon\Carbon::parse(DB::raw("`publish_date`"))->addWeeks(1)
]); ``

According to this:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/mass-updating-table-to-set-value-of-column-to-value-of-another-column

Laravel documentation for Basic Updates:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-updates

Carbon documentation for addition and subtraction:

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

Comment: Thank you for an answer. The problem with that approach is that you don't add +1 week to **existing** date, instead you just overwrite it with +1 week **from now**

Comment: Sorry, I did not pay attention to that. My answer was updated.

Comment: This approach is inefficient, because it retrieves `publish_date` for every single record, unnecessarily loading the database