# Laravel Eloquent MySQL DateTime field update with Interval gives an error

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, eloquent, intervals

I'm trying to update DateTime fields for all records by adding 1 day using interval with eloquent like that

```
TestModel::update(['date' => \DB::raw('DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)')]);
```

But I'm getting this error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "1": syntax error (SQL: update "test" set "date" = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Which doesn't make sense as if I use this query directly in MYSQL (using HeidiSQL) it works if I remove quotes around table and fields names.

```
update test set date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

I've also tried without using `DATE_ADD` function but the same error occurs

```
\DB::raw('date + INTERVAL 1 DAY')
```

Adding quotes around fields doesn't make any difference.

All other queries for insert, delete, update operations work without issues.
I've checked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208579/mass-date-update-using-eloquent) and it seems like the correct format for eloquent, so what is wrong here?

Laravel 5.8 (I know it's outdated)
MySQL 8.0.34
PHP 7.4

UPDATE: It gives an error in unit test which uses SQLite and it doesn't support INTERVAL

Comment: I'm unable to learn the exact rules and documentation does not clarify it, but I often find that `INTERVAL` expressions in MySQL will trigger a syntax error unless the figure is quoted. So it's worth trying `INTERVAL '1' DAY` as opposed to `INTERVAL 1 DAY`. You can first try this in your favourite MySQL client.

Comment: what if you use `\DB::statement()` (execute plain mysql query in laravel)?

Comment: its best to not mix [tag:eloquent] and [tag:laravel-query-builder] given that eloquent tend to use prepared statement and may bound your parameters as string. try dump the actual executed query.

Comment: I've tried using statement. but I just figured that it's failing in unit tests which uses sqlite and it doesn't support intervals

Comment: Did you try to put date in quotes? TestModel::update(['date' => \DB::raw('DATE_ADD(`"date"`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)')]);

Comment: Sounds like you should no run your tests using SQLite?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's very common practice in Laravel to use SQLite inmemory database for unit testing as you don't need to setup anything to make it work but it introduces some incompatibility issues

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to use MySQL features, you should't use any other database system

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use backticks  (not because `date` is reserved word but in general wrap columns in backticks)

```php
TestModel::update(['date' => \DB::raw('DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 DAY)')]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but as I mentioned that any type of quotes don't make any difference. The problem turns up to be SQLite which is used for unit testing and it doesn't support `INTERVAL`

Comment: @dgpro , well I think this will help you : https://bannister.me/blog/using-mysql-and-postgres-functions-in-sqlite